# UIActivityViewController Options button

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

In a UIActivityViewController, where does the Options button come from? For example, here's how Safari presents the activity view:

[image]

Next to `apple.com` there's an Options button that lets the user choose a format for sending the data. How can I make that button appear in my app?

Comment: I wonder if this is the "options UI" to which they cryptically allude in [What's New in Sharing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/210/?time=370): “If your app had multiple share extensions previously, you can consolidate them into one by adding an options UI to allow your user to select which functionality they want when they launch your share extension.”

Comment: Hi @matt. I wanted to comment last night, but didn't want to seem uninformed. What's the difference between a share sheet and using the UIActivityViewController? My eyes notice the "Apple" and "apple.com" beneath, in what I thought was something with a public API. But my digging only found various things (including meta data?) that became available in iOS 13. If this uses `UIActivityViewController` but isn't what I'd call a share sheet, could you tell me what it is? Or at least point me in the right direction to understand?

Comment: @dfd Well maybe UIActivityViewController _is_ the share sheet. (I assumed they meant the thing in the Share Extension at the other end.) I wish they wouldn't talk so loosely. And even so, what _is_ the "Options UI"? I don't see how UIActivityViewController gives me a place for that. That's what my question is about. :)

Comment: @matt Did you ever make any progress with this? I can't find any documentation or other posts about this. Seems like maybe it's Apple specific?

Comment: @re_zacks I didn't. Let me know if you find out anything. Apple certainly uses it in powerful ways.