# How FaceTime is able to add this button to the Share Sheet's preview header?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm curious how FaceTime is customizing the share sheet? Specifically, how are they modifying the preview header to include an "Add name" button.

Note: Tapping the "Add name" button, present an alert with a textfield that allow us to input the meeting's name.

Is it FaceTime using some private API?

[image: FaceTime Share Sheet]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329507/uiactivityviewcontroller-options-button. I didn't get any solution there either. Evidently Apple can do this and we can't.

Comment: @matt Oh i see. Looks like a possible way is subclassing the UIActivityViewController. I just found this library: https://github.com/naturaln0va/VisualActivityViewController

Comment: Well, let me know if you find a real way.